# Inserting a pandas dataframe into snowflake table using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to insert a pandas data frame into snowflake table using sqlalchemy

My dataframe looks like
df =

```
    FRUITS        VEGETABLES
0    apple        potato
1    banana   onion
2    mango    beans
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

# account details
account_identifier = 'account_identifier'
user = 'user_login_name'
password = 'password'
database_name = 'database_name'
schema_name = 'schema_name'

conn_string = f"snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account_identifier}/{database_name}/{schema_name}"
engine = create_engine(conn_string)

table_name = 'my_table'

if_exists = 'append'

if __name__ = '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
    with engine.connect() as con:
     df.to_sql(name=table_name.lower(), con=con, if_exists=if_exists, index=False, method=pd_writer)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 79
invalid identifier '"FRUITS"'
```

I don't understand why this is giving an error even though my table schema has only two columns

Comment: It looks like you indeed have a table called "my_table" with two columns, but they have different names. Your code tries to insert data using the column names identifiers but fails to find them in the existing table. Could you please check that and clarify if the goal is to create a new table with FRUITS and VEGETABLES, or you want to append the columns from the dataframe to an existing table with different column names?

Comment: Can you try reading the csv without headers, df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', header=None) and see if it resolves the issue.